# how to connect multiple clients on server

Tags: server, port-forwarding, tcp-ip, netcat

> nc -l -vv -p 7795

This is the command for listen the port
But i can connect only one client by using(nc localhost 7795) to the port,tell me how to connect multiple client to the port 7795

Answer (score 1):

The `nc` utility cannot handle multiple connections *simultaneously*. It can handle them *sequentially*, though.

You could use the `-k` option so that the connections that are "waiting in line" from subsequent clients get handled after the first client disconnects. For example:

```
# terminal A: 'server'
$ nc -l -vv -p 8000 -k
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 8000)
Connection from localhost 45080 received!
hi
bye
Connection from localhost 45082 received!
hi
bye

#terminal B: 'client 1'
nc localhost 8000
hi
bye
^C
```

Although terminal C tries to establish a connection before terminal B disconnects, the 'server' on terminal A automatically picks it up and handles it afterward.

```
# terminal C: 'client 2'
nc localhost 8000
hi
bye
^C
```

---

**[EDIT-1]:** If you're scripting something and need multiple ones, you could consider launching multiple instances of `nc` 'servers' listening on a set of pre-defined ports and then decide which ones to connect to, but that can get more complicated.

**[EDIT-2]:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29780420/4594973) answer to basically the same question, which mentions other tool alternatives.